# Error installing mod_wsgi 3.1

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi 3.1 on Ubuntu 9.10 and am getting this error when I attempt to make

```
root@me:/src/mod_wsgi-3.1$ ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.6
checking for apxs2... /usr/bin/apxs2
checking Apache version... 2.2.12
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

root@me:/src/mod_wsgi-3.1$ sudo make
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config  -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static i486-linux-gnu-gcc -prefer-pic -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread     -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0  -I/usr/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo

/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool: line 970: i486-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install gcc compiler properly, it looks to not all be there, or possibly not at all.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you need apache-dev
try this

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

after this try

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.6
```

And run well :-)
greats!

Answer (score 2):

**apxs: command not found**

If you get an error while running configure that says:
apxs: command not found.

Then you will need to install the apache2-threaded-dev package (Ubuntu package name, may be different on different distros.

**apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev**